# Missing dll function detection

Tags: dll, import

I want to ask whether there is some way to detect missing function in DLL included to my application, while application is running. I know about possibility to import function manualy using HMODULE and check it when calling this function, but I don't want to solve each function call in this way. Idea is to cover function call with some try-catch block or something similar, which doesn't cause application crash. Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: This is normally very easy to diagnose, your program won't start.  So no point to test *while* you are running, the fact that you *are* running is sufficient proof that you don't have a problem :)

Comment: I forgot write that I'm using delay load just due to reason of non-starting, so my program starts a if function is called, than crashes.

Comment: Is there any point whatsoever to not test your program first without /delayload???  How to trap runtime errors is otherwise well documented at MSDN.

Comment: Yes, it's school project requiring delay load usage. Task is: how to detect that function is included in dll while application is running.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9e046h.aspx), in C/C++ with MSVC compiler you can do something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#define FACILITY_VISUALCPP  ((LONG)0x6d)
#define VcppException(sev,err)  ((sev) | (FACILITY_VISUALCPP<<16) | err)
const DWORD LIB_NOT_FOUND = VcppException(ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR, ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND);
const DWORD FUNC_NOT_FOUND = VcppException(ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR, ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND);

__try
{
    MyDLLFunction();
}
__except(GetExceptionCode() == LIB_NOT_FOUND || GetExceptionCode() == FUNC_NOT_FOUND
         ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)
{
    printf("library or function not found\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling the function, which will generate an EntryPointNotFoundException if the function doesn't exist. For example (VB.NET):

```
Dim MissingFunction as Boolean = False
Try
    TheFunction()
Catch ex As System.EntryPointNotFoundException
    MissingFunction = True
End Try
```